# Get last inserted id in oracle with php

Tags: php, oracle

I have two tables created with this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE t2 (id NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY);
```

Im inserting some data into t1 and then i need to insert the ID generated in that insert into t2.

For example:

```
"insert into t1 (name, description) values ('asd','dsa')"
**getting that autogenerated ID
"insert into t2 (idFromt1,name) values (idFromt1,'sarasa')"
```

I saw many examples doing:

```
"insert into t1 (name, description) values ('asd','dsa') returning ID into inserted_id";
```

But i cant/dont know how to retrieve that "inserted_id" variable from php to make the second insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve Oracle last inserted IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811283/retrieve-oracle-last-inserted-identity)

Comment: Oh, didnt knew that.

Comment: @CodeSpirit I can’t see how this is a duplicate of that question. This one’s about PHP and the other isn’t.

Answer (score 3):

I was googling about PDO and come into this:

```
$qry="INSERT INTO t1 (NOMBRE) VALUES ('sarasa') returning ID into :inserted_id";

$parsed = oci_parse($this->conn, $qry);

oci_bind_by_name($parsed, ":inserted_id", $idNumber,32);
oci_execute($parsed);
echo $idNumber;
```

so i asumed oci_bind_by_name was one direction only, but no. 
That saves into the variable $idNumber the generated id and was exactly what i needed. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can (should?) use the `returning` value.

For example, with PDO :

```
$query = "insert into t1 (name, description) values ('asd','dsa') returning ID";

$stmt = $pdo->query($query);

$id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [PDO::lastInsertID](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Don't use

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;
```

Because it's not safe if some other insert query will be executed before select and it will not work for you in a transaction.

Comment: Oracle driver does not support lastInsertId()

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers quite worked for me - I kept getting NULL out as my last inserted indentity. By chance (literally trying everything) I found that before you do:

```
$stmt->bindParam('idfoo', $idfoo, PDO::PARAM_INT, 8);
```

You need to set $idfoo as an integer. I don't know why. Like so:

```
$idfoo = (int)null;
```

It can be any integer but this is clearer for me that I am just "initialising" it to an empty value of a certain type.

Full example:

```
$query = "insert into t2 (name, description) values (:name, :description) returning ID into :idfoo";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);  

$name = 'adsjim';
$description = 'lead dev';

$params = array('name'=>$name, 'description'=>$description);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
      $stmt->bindValue($key,$value);
}
$idfoo = (int)null;
$stmt->bindParam('idfoo', $idfoo, PDO::PARAM_INT, 8);

$stmt->execute();
// insert id is now in the $idfoo variable
var_dump($idfoo);
```

The identity column is literally called ID in the database - replace with whatever your column is called.

Comment: This is actually because PHP 8 has started to give importance to data types. You may have to define (int) or (array) in many cases. Refer to the PHP 8 migration docs to learn better about the differences in PHP 7.4 and 8.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php

Answer (score 0):

This question is about PHP using PDO and Oracle. None of these solutions worked for me, Emepese's answer uses the native OCI driver instead of PDO, and `PDO::lastInsertId` does NOT work with Oracle.

Cid's answer got me the closest, along with an answer from [how to get sequence id of last inserted record in oracle 11g xe with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902479/2124401)

But my situation was a little more complex. I already had a query with `$stmt->prepare($query)` and `$stmt->execute(array('name'=>$name, 'desc'=>$desc));` To make it work, I wrote this:

```
$query = "insert into t1 (name, desc) values (:name, :desc) returning ID into :PK_ID";
// move params to an array:
$params = array('name'=>$name, 'desc'=>$desc);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
      $stmt->bindValue($key,$value);
}
$stmt->bindParam('PK_ID',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,32);
// Important! Remove all parameters from the execute command:
$stmt->execute();
// insert id is now in the $id variable - do something with it
echo "I inserted $id!";
```

I hope this helps someone else save hours trying to play with Identity columns, Oracle Sequences, and bind parameters.

Answer (score 0):

@Volod’s answer is correct, but here is a fuller example of how you would go about it using `PDO`.

```php
$db = new PDO(…);                                               //  1
$prepared = 'insert into t1 (name, description) values (?,?)';  //  2
$prepared -> execute(['asd','dsa']);                            //  3
$id = $db -> lastInsertId();                                    //  4
//  etc
```

This example uses a prepared statement for safety.

1. Create a new PDO object connecting to the database.
2. Create a new PDOStatement object which contains a prepared statement. A prepared statement is interpreted without actual data; the question marks (`?`) are placeholders for the data. Even though they represent strings, the *don’t* include quotes.
3. Run the prepared statement with an array of values to be inserted.
4. Regardless of the actual DBMS, PDO will fetch the newest auto generated `id` with the `lastInsertId()` method.

One of the points of PDO is that it handles the differences between DBMSs by using its own methods. In this case, we don’t care how Oracle fetches the `id`, but rely on PDO to work it out.

Using prepared statements is important if you’re using data from an untrusted sources (such as a user) or if you need to run a statement multiple times. If you’re just running it once with trusted data, you can do it more simply:

```php
$db = new PDO(…);
$db -> exec ("insert into t1 (name, description) values ('asd','dsa')';
$id = $db -> lastInsertId();
//  etc
```

Answer (score -2):

Either use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php)
or

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;
```

Comment: `MAX(id)` is a terrible idea. It depends on race